# CRC16's calculation doesn't return "0" in the receiver

Tags: c, crc, lookup-tables, crc16

I have already done a CRC16 calculation algorithm, and it works very well. Now, as a next step, I am trying to write a CRC16 algorithm using a lookup table.

First of all, I create a dummy message with some random values, pass it to the algorithm with its length, and the result is stored into a variable named `crc`.

Then, I add the `crc` into my data at the end of the array, and I pass it to the algorithm in order to calculate a new crc (`crc_2`).

I expected that `crc_2` was equal to zero, but every time its value is different from that.

These are the data:

- data[6]= {0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40,0,0};
- Crc_polynomial = 0xA001;
- Crc_initial_value = 0XFFFF;

---

```c
uint16_t crc16_tab[256] =
{
    0x0000, 0xA001, 0xE003, 0x4002, 0x6007, 0xC006, 0x8004, 0x2005, 0xC00E, 0x600F, 0x200D, 0x800C, 0xA009, 0x0008, 0x400A, 0xE00B,
    0x201D, 0x801C, 0xC01E, 0x601F, 0x401A, 0xE01B, 0xA019, 0x0018, 0xE013, 0x4012, 0x0010, 0xA011, 0x8014, 0x2015, 0x6017, 0xC016,
    0x403A, 0xE03B, 0xA039, 0x0038, 0x203D, 0x803C, 0xC03E, 0x603F, 0x8034, 0x2035, 0x6037, 0xC036, 0xE033, 0x4032, 0x0030, 0xA031,
    0x6027, 0xC026, 0x8024, 0x2025, 0x0020, 0xA021, 0xE023, 0x4022, 0xA029, 0x0028, 0x402A, 0xE02B, 0xC02E, 0x602F, 0x202D, 0x802C,
    0x8074, 0x2075, 0x6077, 0xC076, 0xE073, 0x4072, 0x0070, 0xA071, 0x407A, 0xE07B, 0xA079, 0x0078, 0x207D, 0x807C, 0xC07E, 0x607F,
    0xA069, 0x0068, 0x406A, 0xE06B, 0xC06E, 0x606F, 0x206D, 0x806C, 0x6067, 0xC066, 0x8064, 0x2065, 0x0060, 0xA061, 0xE063, 0x4062,
    0xC04E, 0x604F, 0x204D, 0x804C, 0xA049, 0x0048, 0x404A, 0xE04B, 0x0040, 0xA041, 0xE043, 0x4042, 0x6047, 0xC046, 0x8044, 0x2045,
    0xE053, 0x4052, 0x0050, 0xA051, 0x8054, 0x2055, 0x6057, 0xC056, 0x205D, 0x805C, 0xC05E, 0x605F, 0x405A, 0xE05B, 0xA059, 0x0058,
    0xA0E9, 0x00E8, 0x40EA, 0xE0EB, 0xC0EE, 0x60EF, 0x20ED, 0x80EC, 0x60E7, 0xC0E6, 0x80E4, 0x20E5, 0x00E0, 0xA0E1, 0xE0E3, 0x40E2,
    0x80F4, 0x20F5, 0x60F7, 0xC0F6, 0xE0F3, 0x40F2, 0x00F0, 0xA0F1, 0x40FA, 0xE0FB, 0xA0F9, 0x00F8, 0x20FD, 0x80FC, 0xC0FE, 0x60FF,
    0xE0D3, 0x40D2, 0x00D0, 0xA0D1, 0x80D4, 0x20D5, 0x60D7, 0xC0D6, 0x20DD, 0x80DC, 0xC0DE, 0x60DF, 0x40DA, 0xE0DB, 0xA0D9, 0x00D8,
    0xC0CE, 0x60CF, 0x20CD, 0x80CC, 0xA0C9, 0x00C8, 0x40CA, 0xE0CB, 0x00C0, 0xA0C1, 0xE0C3, 0x40C2, 0x60C7, 0xC0C6, 0x80C4, 0x20C5,
    0x209D, 0x809C, 0xC09E, 0x609F, 0x409A, 0xE09B, 0xA099, 0x0098, 0xE093, 0x4092, 0x0090, 0xA091, 0x8094, 0x2095, 0x6097, 0xC096,
    0x0080, 0xA081, 0xE083, 0x4082, 0x6087, 0xC086, 0x8084, 0x2085, 0xC08E, 0x608F, 0x208D, 0x808C, 0xA089, 0x0088, 0x408A, 0xE08B,
    0x60A7, 0xC0A6, 0x80A4, 0x20A5, 0x00A0, 0xA0A1, 0xE0A3, 0x40A2, 0xA0A9, 0x00A8, 0x40AA, 0xE0AB, 0xC0AE, 0x60AF, 0x20AD, 0x80AC,
    0x40BA, 0xE0BB, 0xA0B9, 0x00B8, 0x20BD, 0x80BC, 0xC0BE, 0x60BF, 0x80B4, 0x20B5, 0x60B7, 0xC0B6, 0xE0B3, 0x40B2, 0x00B0, 0xA0B1
};

uint16_t fast_crc16(uint16_t crc,uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t len) 
{
    while (len--)
    {
        crc = crc16_tab[(crc >> 8) ^ *buffer++] ^ (crc << 8);
    }

    return (crc);
}

int main() {

    /*DUMMY MESSAGE*/
    uint8_t data[6] = {0x10,0x20, 0X30,0X40,0,0};
    uint16_t crc = 0;
    uint16_t crc_2 = 0;

    /*FIRST CRC*/
    crc = fast_crc16(0XFFFF,data, 4);

    /*COPY CRC INTO DATA*/
    memcpy((void*)&data[4], (void*)&crc_2, 2);

    /*SECOND CRC*/
    crc_2 = fast_crc16(crc,data, 6);

    printf("%x", crc_2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're putting the computed CRC in `crc`, but then copy `crc_2` to the end of the message, which you set to zero. You want to copy `crc`, not `crc_2`.

Second, you are using `memcpy()` to copy the CRC to the end of the message, which could do one of two different things depending on the endianess of your machine. To make it independent of the endianess of your machine, and to do the right thing, you need to copy the high byte of the CRC to `data[4]`, and the low byte to `data[5]`:

```c
    data[4] = crc >> 8;
    data[5] = crc;
```

Third, your second CRC calculation needs to start with the same initial value of your CRC definition, which is `0xffff`. Not `crc`. So:

```c
    crc_2 = fast_crc16(0xffff, data, 6);
```

Then you'll get zero.